# How do I enable Java in my browsers

Tags: windows-7, java

I uninstalled Java using Add/Remove Progams, rebooted then installed Java from their website.

The installation was successful but the plugin isn't activated in any browser, IE, Firefox or Chrome.

Can anyone help?

---

OS Version: Microsoft Windows 7 Ultimate, Service Pack 1, 64 bit
Processor: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3610QM CPU @ 2.30GHz, Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9
Processor Count: 8
RAM: 16266 MB
Graphics Card: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 680M, -2048 MB
Hard Drives: C: Total - 953733 MB, Free - 385774 MB;
Motherboard: Alienware, M17xR4

Comment: what java did you install specifically

Comment: I downloaded the **jre-7u45-windows-x64** file from [link](http://javadl.sun.com/webapps/download/AutoDL?BundleId=81821).

Comment: do the plugins appear in the browser, in a disabled state, or do they not appear at all? have you rebooted (yes it is needed after jre install), and followed the instructions here for firefox? http://kb.mozillazine.org/Java#Enabling_Java

Comment: Java shows up in the plugins for each, Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Comment: I believe the Java installation is corrupted every time. I believe so because the Java-based app, **jDownloader** does not launch.

Answer (score 0):

Download the 32Bit version, the browsers are 32Bit and not 64Bit, so the 64Bit plugin doesn't work.

Comment: Isn't **Firefox** 64-bit?

Comment: I'm afraid installing the 32-bit version after removal of Java and a reboot has **not** solved the problem.

Comment: the normal Firefox is 32Bit. Have you activated it in the Addons/Plugins options?

Comment: Yes, it was activated in the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Windows control panel to go into the java console and enable it there.

Comment: Alright, when I installed Java 7 update 45 x64, there appeared **Configure Java** shortcut in my Start Menu and a **Java** entry in the Control Panel. However, neither launches; clicking on either does absolutely nothing.